# Get names of field schema from Pig

Tags: java, schema, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm working on a JsonStorage for Pig. Everything works fine, but at least I need to get the names of the fields (i.e. crdate, name, positions) from the pig schema.

```
| A | crdate: bytearray | name: bytearray | positions: bytearray |
```

Actually I extend my class by StoreFunc that provides no function to get the names of the fields.

```
public class PigJsonStorage extends StoreFunc { .. }
```

Can anybody help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disclaimer: I'm a little new to pig myself, and haven't implemented a storage class yet.

It looks to me like StoreFunc has a method for this: [StoreFunc.checkSchema(ResourceSchema s)](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/api/org/apache/pig/StoreFunc.html#checkSchema%28org.apache.pig.ResourceSchema%29).  I would think you could just capture the schema from that for use during the write.

Answer (score 0):

There's a class [JsonMetadata](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/JsonMetadata.html) that returns [ResourceSchema](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/api/org/apache/pig/ResourceSchema.html) which has a method returning an array of fields.

Comment: As I see, getSchema tells me the schema of the loaded data, but I generate new fields during processing MapReduce. So I need the schema just before the tuples are stored to the file system :)